# ldap unboundid: create custom attribute for an entry

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

```
    try {
        LDAPResult result = getConnection().modify(
                 "dn: cn=jacob.kranz,cn=example,cn=com",
                 "changetype: modify",
                 "replace: forgotPasswordAttribute",
                 "forgotPasswordAttribute: testValueForNewAttribute");
    } catch (LDIFException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LDAPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to add the forgotPassword attribute for the given entry.  According to the UnboundId documenatation (found [here](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/ModificationType.html)), when doing a replace (see param 3), it will create the attribute if the attribute does not already exist.  However, I keep getting an error `forgotPassword: attribute type undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace modification type will add an attribute to the entry if the entry doesn't already have that attribute, but the attribute type needs to be defined in the schema and allowed by the object classes contained in the entry.

Comment: How would I go about adding the attribute to the schema?  I apologize, I'm pretty new to LDAP as a whole.